# How to change date format to day,dd-mm-yy using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, date-format

I have a date string in the format `dd/mm/yyyy` and want to change it.

I want to convert it into format `DayOfweek, dd-mm-yyyy`. For example `10/7/2016` should be converted to `Sun, 10-7-2016`.

How can i do this work?

Comment: Please add the code you've tried so far to the question

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Date()` object to convert string to date and get day name.

```js
var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
var dateStr = "10/7/2016";

var date = new Date(dateStr.split("/").reverse().join("-"));
var dayName = days[date.getDay()];
var newFormat = dayName + ", " + dateStr.replace(/\//g, "-");

console.log(newFormat);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a function like this:

```
function date_format(d_str){
    var weekdays = [ "Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"];
    var d_s = d_str.split("/");
    return weekdays[new Date(d_s[2]+'-'+d_s[1]+'-'+d_s[0]).getDay()]+', '+d_s[0]+'-'+d_s[1]+'-'+d_s[2];
}
console.debug(date_format('10/7/2016'));
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/220tugyx/2/